# react-native image resizeMode : How to avoid blanks

Tags: css, image, react-native

I'm currently having troubles with Image resizeMode.
My component is behaving the way i want only in 'cover'.

this is the resizeMode i want (contain) with the incorrect behaviour :
[image: this is the resizeMode i want (contain) with the incorrect behaviour :]

this is the resizeMode i dont want (cover) with correct behaviour
[image: this is the resizeMode i dont want (cover) with correct behaviour]

How can I avoid those blanks ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the lib ***https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-auto-height-image***.

This lib helps me to solve many problems that I had when I was working with images.

Comment: Thanks combined with a Dimension.get("windows").width it worked perfectly